# ¿Como eliminar un registro de una coleccion?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Al momento de regresar el resultado de una consulta quiero depurar el resultado, mi intención es, si no cumple con la condición que se elimine de la matríz, sin embargo se eliminan todas, este es un ejemplo del resultado:

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 4,
        "codigo": "6WQRLIRO",
        "nombre": "proo3",
        "fecha_emision": "2017-10-08",
        "fecha_limite": "2017-10-28",
        "activa": "si",
        "created_at": "2017-10-18 12:53:12",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-18 12:53:12",
        "descripcion": null,
        "url": null,
        "condiciones": []
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 6,
        "codigo": "QDA6M-6P",
        "nombre": "Garrafón gratis",
        "fecha_emision": "2017-10-01",
        "fecha_limite": "2017-11-30",
        "activa": "no",
        "created_at": "2017-10-20 08:47:55",
        "updated_at": "2017-10-20 08:47:55",
        "descripcion": null,
        "url": null,
        "condiciones": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "promocion_id": 6,
                "tipo_condicion": "sexo",
                "valor_condicion": "mujer",
                "created_at": "2017-10-20 08:47:55",
                "updated_at": "2017-10-20 08:47:55"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "promocion_id": 6,
                "tipo_condicion": "padre/madre",
                "valor_condicion": "padre/madre",
                "created_at": "2017-10-20 08:47:55",
                "updated_at": "2017-10-20 08:47:55"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Este es el código:

```
foreach ($promociones as $key => $promocion) {
        if ($promocion->nombre == 'Circulo') {
          $promociones->forget($key);
        }
        foreach ($promocion->condiciones as $condicion) {
          if ($condicion->tipo_condicion == 'colonia') {
            if ($condicion->valor_condicion != $colonia) {
              $promociones->forget($key);

            }
          }

        }
      }
```

Lo que pretendo es que elimine sólo la que no cumpla con la condición, sin embargo se borran todas las que tengan cualquier tipo de condiciones

Answer (score 0):

El error podría estar en la variable `$colonia` **(no se puede ver el valor en el ejemplo presentado)**, ya que si `$colonia` es nula, o tiene un valor no contenido en ninguna condición, todas las promociones serán eliminadas.

Comment: Probablemente, y en algunas ocaciones la variable no tendria valor, entonces, que recomiendas hacer?

Answer (score 0):

**$colonia** esta indefinida, por lo que cualquier registro con un valor en este campo va a ser diferente y va a desaparecer.

De todas formas, una vez definida, mi recomendación es que hagas esto en la propia consulta y evitar hacer bucles con el resultado:

```
Promociones::where('nombre','Circulo')
  ->whereHas('condiciones', function ($query) use($colonia) {
    $query->where('valor_condicion', $colonia);
  })
  ->with('condiciones')
  ->get();
```